# Mysql devuelve UN resultado SUSTITUYENDO una subconsulta por valor devuelto por ella. SI NO, devuelve DOS

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

tengo una duda sobre **MySQL** que me plantea un alumno y no sé responder. Me estoy volviendo loca, a ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

Tengo la siguiente consulta (obviando que no es óptima, pues se puede hacer sin una de las subconsultas), que **devuelve dos resultados**:

```
SELECT p.nombre,p.precio FROM producto p INNER JOIN fabricante f
on p.codigo_fabricante=f.codigo
WHERE p.precio=
(SELECT MIN(p.precio) FROM producto WHERE p.codigo_fabricante=
(SELECT f.codigo FROM fabricante f WHERE f.nombre LIKE "Hewlett-Packard"));
```

**Sin embargo**, si lanzo primero la subconsulta:

```
SELECT MIN(p.precio) FROM producto p WHERE p.codigo_fabricante=
(SELECT f.codigo FROM fabricante f WHERE f.nombre LIKE "Hewlett-Packard");
```

E introduzco después directamente el valor devuelto de la siguiente forma, **devuelve un solo resultado**:

```
SELECT p.nombre,p.precio FROM producto p INNER JOIN fabricante f
on p.codigo_fabricante=f.codigo WHERE p.precio= 60;
```

**¿Sabéis por qué se obtienen resultados distintos?**

Mil gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola. Sería bueno que agregues a la pregunta un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable, con las tablas que intervienen y un pequeño set de datos que producen los resultados que comentas. Sin estar en tu contexto es complicado poder ayudarte. [Puedes crear un fiddle aquí](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) y poner el enlace en la pregunta.

Comment: Te recomiendo que tal y como dice @A.Cedano introduzcas valores de ejemplo para que te podamos ayudar como debe ser..